# compiler complains unhandled IOException even though function signature throws it

Tags: java

I have a class, in which the static factory method uses `computeIfAbsent()` to return an instance:

```
public class TrafficMonitor {
   private static ConcurrentMap<String, TrafficMonitor> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private String busNumber;

   //private constructor could throw an IOException
   private TrafficMonitor(String busNumber) throws IOException {
       this.busNumber = busNumber;
       // it needs to be in constructor because it call a 3rd party API to instantiate an object which throws IOException
       doIoOperation();
   }

   // static factory method to return a instance of this class
   public static TrafficMonitor forBus(String busNumber) throws IOException {
       // Compiler error: Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException
       return instances.computeIfAbsent(busNumber, TrafficMonitor::new);
   }

}
```

The private constructor throws IOException, in static factory function `forBus(String busNumber)` even though I have `throws IOException` in signature, compiler still complains that `unhandled exception: java.io.IOException`. Why? How to get rid of it?

Another question: in this example, does `TrafficMonitor::new` automatically get the argument/parameter `busNumber` from the `forBus(String busNumber)` function or how does it create the instance with the private constructor which requires an argument `String busNumber` ?

Comment: computeIfAbsent expects a Function as argument. The signature of Function's SAM is `R apply(T t)`. As you see, A Function may not throw an IOException. But your constructor does throw an IOException. So TrafficMonitor::new is not a Function. So you can't pass that as argument to computeIfAbsent().

Comment: Maybe you are right, I am not familiar with the double colon, how to get rid of it?

Comment: The clean way to get rid of it is to avoid doing IO operations in a constructor. A constructor isn't supposed to do that. It's supposed to create an object. The less clean way is to pass a lambda that calls the constructor, catches IOException, and rethrows it as a runtime exception.

Comment: `A constructor isn't supposed to do that`, well, there is no such rule, I think it depends. In my case, it makes sense to do that since my class is a wrapper to an 3rd party API which throws `IOException` during instantiation.  With that being said, it would be nice if you could provide code example for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computeIfAbsent` expects a `Function` as argument. The signature of Function's SAM is `R apply(T t)`. As you see, a `Function` may not throw an `IOException`. But your constructor does throw an `IOException`. So `TrafficMonitor::new` is not a Function. So you can't pass that as argument to `computeIfAbsent()`.

Clean way: don't do IO in a constructor:

```
public class TrafficMonitor {
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, TrafficMonitor> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private String busNumber;
    private boolean initialized;

    private TrafficMonitor(String busNumber) {
        this.busNumber = busNumber;
    }

    private synchronized void initialize() throws IOException {
        if (!initialized) {
            doIoOperation();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }

    public static TrafficMonitor forBus(String busNumber) throws IOException {
        TrafficMonitor result = instances.computeIfAbsent(busNumber, TrafficMonitor::new);
        result.initialize();
        return result;
   }
}
```

Less clean way: rethrow IOException as a runtime exception

```
private TrafficMonitor(String busNumber) {
    this.busNumber = busNumber;
    try { 
        doIoOperation();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw UnchedkIOException(e);
    }
}
```

or

```
public static TrafficMonitor forBus(String busNumber) {
    return instances.computeIfAbsent(busNumber, busNumber -> {
        try {
            return new TrafficMonitor(busNumber);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw UnchedkIOException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `SAM` stand for in your answer?

Comment: Single Abstract Method. That's the condition that an interface must fulfill in order to be a functional interface, i.e. be able to be used as a the type of a lambda or method reference.

Comment: I like the clean way, but it violates the logic I am trying to achieve, if you take a close look at my code of `forBus(String busNumber)`, the instance of `TrafficMonitor` is the same one for the same `busNumber`. That's it is a "singleton" per `busNumber`. The `doIoOperation()` is supposed to be executed only when creating a new instance of `TrafficMonitor`.  Could you please modify your clean solution code to meet this requirement as well?

Comment: Oh yes, you have a boolean flag to control the initialization.